# Flask - Postgres 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an issue with Flask and Postgres. Below I'll link my app.py, models.py, and views.py. The 400 error comes whenever I try to define a new User and add it to the database. I checked that my server is running in postgres and that I'm connected to the db. All of my tables were properly created and I was able to pass new users in through in the python shell. Any thoughts?

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://user:pass@localhost/mydb'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from views import *
from models import *

if __name__=='__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from app import app
from app import db
from models import User
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request

@app.route('/')
def home():
    #this will look different for logged in and logged out users
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/about')
def about():
    #notes
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    #notes
    return render_template('contact.html')

@app.route('/blog')
def blog():
    #notes
    return render_template('blog.html')

@app.route('/podcast')
def podcast():
    #notes
    return render_template('podcast.html')

@app.route('/shop')
def shop():
    #notes
    return render_template('shop.html')

@app.route('/add_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_user():
    user = User(request.form['username'], request.form['email'])
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('add_user.html')
```

**models.py**

```
from app import db
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

**add_user.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Add User</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="/add_user" method="post">
      <label>username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
      <label>email:</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view.py instead

```
def add_user():
   user = User(request.form['username'], request.form['email'])
   db.session.add(user)
   db.session.commit()
   return render_template('add_user.html')
```

try this code

```
def add_user():
   if request.method == 'POST':
     user = User(request.form['username'], request.form['email'])
     db.session.add(user)
     db.session.commit()
return render_template('add_user.html')
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#the-request-object

If you send get request to /add_user, flask dont see form variable username and password, request.form  work only from post and put requsest.

From documentation: 
"What happens if the key does not exist in the form attribute? In that case a special KeyError is raised. You can catch it like a standard KeyError but if you don’t do that, a HTTP 400 Bad Request error page is shown instead. So for many situations you don’t have to deal with that problem. "

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#the-request-object
 . If you send get request to /add_user, flask dont see form variable username and password, because he wait post requsest. 

From documentation: 
"You can catch it like a standard KeyError but if you don’t do that, a HTTP 400 Bad Request error page is shown instead. "

Comment: Thanks @hardtyz that solved the issue. Although, now I am unsure why the user object isn't being committed to the database.